# How to set a bit based on a value existing in a table

Tags: t-sql

I have a table. I have 2 variables, one is a `bit`, the other is an `int`.

Table: `WorkGroupCollectionDetail`

Variables: `@WorkgroupID int, @IsFSBP bit`

The table has `WorkGroupId int PK` and `WorkGroupCollectionCode varchar PK`. That's it.

I can run a query like this:

```
SELECT WorkGroupId 
FROM WorkGroupCollectionDetail 
WHERE WorkGroupCollectionCode = 'FSBP'
```

and it gives me a list of `WorkGroupID`.

So what I need to do is if the value of `@WorkgroupID` is inside the results of that query, I need to set the bit variable to true.

Comment: how is @BitVariable related to the rows in TestTable?

Comment: do you want to `UPDATE` the table with the value or return it in the `SELECT`?  what are you doing with the bit variable when you set it?

Comment: Bit variable is not related to the rows in the table. I want to set BitVariable to true if testid is part of the query results and false if it is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select @IsFBSP = case
  when exists (
    select 42 from WorkGroupDetailCollection
      where WorkGroupCollectionCode = 'FSBP' and WorkGroupId = @WorkGroupId ) then 1
  else 0 end
```

which is logically equivalent to:

```
select @IsFBSP = case
  when @WorkGroupId in (
    select WorkGroupId from WorkGroupDetailCollection
      where WorkGroupCollectionCode = 'FSBP' ) then 1
  else 0 end
```

A query using `EXISTS` often performs better than a query using `IN`.  You can check the execution plans to see how they compare in your particular case.

Note that these examples include setting the bit value to zero as well as one.

Comment: I'm not really following this, but it's not what I need sorry.

Comment: Is the updated answer a better match for your updated question?

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the `SELECT` to include the check for the `WorkGroupId` and update the `@IsFSBP` accordingly:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT WorkGroupId 
          FROM WorkGroupCollectionDetail 
          WHERE WorkGroupCollectionCode = 'FSBP'
             AND WorkGroupId = @WorkgroupID)
BEGIN
   SELECT @IsFSBP = 1;
END
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7825/5)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're looking for

```
Set @BitVariable = count(*)
From TestTable 
WHERE TestCode = 'TestValue' and TestID = @TestID
```

Comment: I will try to re-edit my question. I knew I wasn't asking it right.

Comment: consider posting what you've tried so far, it helps us see what you've been thinking